# Why won't expo connect to the app on m'y computer?

Tags: android, expo

I am trying to create a native-react app. But i have issues with native react on m'y computer and i don't understand.

Indeed i create a New app with create-react-native-app, thé app is created successfully. When i run npm start all goes well.

But when i open m'y expo app on my Android and scan thé qrcode i get an error saying localhost doesn't allow connections.
I have already disabled firewalls and so on..
Help please.

I was expecting thé app toi show on my expo app on Android. But it won't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The android device and computer should be on same network (Wifi) so as to be able to scan QR and use the application on android.